# Flutter & Firebase & Provider : Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, callback, provider

Flutter & Firebase & Provider : Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.

I receive this error/warning after upgrading all of my firebase plugin yesterday. I can still run my app. But there is unusual thing happened.

So normally, after the splashscreen(), it will go straight the AppStarter() Screen.

`Splashscreen()` =>  `AppStarter()`

But after upgrading all of my firebase plugin, there is some kind of screen blackout happened in between.

`Splashscreen()` => Blackout => `AppStarter()`
Main file

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('>>> Error Initialization with Firebase');
          return Container();
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamProvider<SystemUser>.value(
            // Our StreamProvider is listening to the user stream and wrapping the MaterialApp
            // It means anythign inside MaterialApp Widget can accessed to the data provided the above stream
            value: AuthService().user,

            //
            child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'RecycleX',
                theme: ThemeData(
                  fontFamily: 'NanumSquare',
                  //primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                  //primarySwatch: primaryColor,
                  //accentColor: Colors.red[600],
                  primaryColor: primaryColor,
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
                ),
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                supportedLocales: [
                  Locale('en', 'US'),
                  Locale('ko', 'KR'),
                ],
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  AppLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                ],
                localeResolutionCallback: (deviceLocale, supportedLocales) {
                  if (userLocale != null) {
                    print('User preferred language is ' +
                        userLocale.languageCode);
                    return userLocale;
                  } else {
                    for (var locale in supportedLocales) {
                      print(locale.languageCode + deviceLocale.languageCode);
                      if (locale.languageCode == deviceLocale.languageCode &&
                          locale.countryCode == deviceLocale.countryCode) {
                        print(deviceLocale.languageCode + ' is supported');
                        return deviceLocale;
                      }
                    }
                    print('>>>>> ' +
                        deviceLocale.languageCode +
                        ' <<<<<< is not supported');
                    return supportedLocales.first;
                  }
                },
                //home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
                initialRoute: '/',
                routes: {
                  '/': (context) => AppStarter(),
                  '/wrapper': (context) => Wrapper(),
                  '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
                  '/signup': (context) => SignUp(),
                  '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
                  '/home_screen_wrapper': (context) => HomeScreenWrapper(),
                  '/camera_wrapper': (context) => CameraWrapper(),
                  '/image_evaluation': (context) => ImageEvaluation(),
                  '/upload_screen': (context) => UploadScreen(),
                  '/test_screen': (context) => TestScreen(),
                  '/profile': (context) => ProfileSetting()
                }
                //home: LoginScreen(),
                ),
          );
        }

        //return Loading();

        return MediaQuery(
          data: new MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window),
          child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Loading(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Error :

```
Restarted application in 1.277ms.
W/DynamiteModule(  965): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(  965): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
I/DynamiteModule(  965): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(  965): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(  965): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
W/DynamiteModule(  965): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(  965): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(  965): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Please give me some idea on how to solve this. I am looking forward to hearing from all of you. I appreciate all sort of comment. Thank you in advance.